# Run a shell script in background

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script which I am calling in Python using `os.system("./name_of_script")`

I would prefer to do this call based on user input(ie a user types "start" and the call is done, and some other stuff in the python program is also done, when a user types "stop" the script is terminated) but i find that this call takes up the whole focus on the terminal (I dont really know the right word for it, but basically the whole program stalls on this call since my  shell script executes until a keyboard interrupt is received). Then when I do a keyboard interrupt, that is the only moment that the shell script stops executing and the rest of the code afterwards is executed. Is this possible in python?

Comment: os.system is waiting until the program it calls  ends. use Popen and just .kill() to kill the process. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: by calling kill() does it do the same behaviour as if i ran the script on the terminal and then pressing Ctrl+C?

Comment: it will kill the process, you call also send a `signal.SIGINT`

Comment: I couldnt get it to terminate, i think it has something to do with setting shell=True when calling Popen this creates a child process which doesn't terminate even when calling kill()

Comment: @user1397215, ...because it starts a shell, rather than starting your process directly. Killing the shell doesn't necessarily kill its children. You'll note that I very explicitly didn't use `shell=True` in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply constructing a `Popen` object, as in:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['./name_of_script'])
```

...starts the named program without blocking on it to complete.

If you later want to see if it's done yet, you can check `p.poll()` for an update on its status.

This is also faster and safer than `os.system()`, in that it doesn't involve a shell (unless the script you're invoking runs one itself), so you aren't exposing yourself to shellshock, shell injection vulnerabilities, or other shell-related issues unnecessarily.